# AngularJS directive that has ng-repeat and works after being re-added to DOM

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

In AngularJS, I need to create a directive that runs ng-repeat. I need to bind that repeat data to the element. Also, once the element has been removed from the DOM and re-added, I need the ng-click directive to work. How can I setup the html for using ng-repeat with data binding. Most importantly, these elements will be removed and re-added and their ng-click event still needs to work.

Here is the inline that I had

```
<li style="" class="news-item text-left" ng-repeat="item in News.GeneralNews">
    <strong>{{item.DateValue | date: "MMM dd yyyy"}}</strong>
    {{item.Preview}}
    <a class="FakeClickable" ng-click="UpdateNews('General',item.index)" 
       data-target="#GeneralModal" data-toggle="modal">Read more...</a>
</li>
```

I don't understand how to make this work. I attempted to copy directive examples, but this seems more complex.

Directive: so far

```
app.directive('compNews', ['$compile',function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AEC',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs)
            {
                element.append($compile(scope.$eval(attrs.actionBtn))(scope));
            },
            templateUrl: '../pages/TemplateUrls/compNews.html'
        }
    }]);
```

My understanding is that I can place this element inside my HTML markup as `<comp-News></comp-News>`

Comment: Not clear what problem you have.

Comment: I tried to create the directive inside a template in another file. Maybe I don't understand the process of creating a directive. But after adding it ng-repeat didn't give me any elements on the DOM.

Comment: Does the run on sentence at the end of my question clarify for you?